# jQuery JSON value

Tags: javascript, json, syntax

I have a REST service that returns a JSON like this:

```
[{"@id":"123","name":"Name"}]
```

and I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out how the hell to get the value for @id. I've tried:

```
var temp =  data['@id'];
var temp = data[0].'@id';
var temp = data[0].['@id'];
```

all of which return errors. Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var temp = data[0]['@id'];`

Using `.property` only accepts symbols you can use in identifiers and is identical to `["property"]`. Since you have array with single object with `"@id"` property and @ can't be used in identifiers, you have to use brackets. This above translates to data -> it's 0th index (index count start from 0) -> its property "@id".

Answer (score 5):

Should be:

```
var temp = data[0]['@id'];
```

Without dot you entered in your last try.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the slution:

```
var temp = data[0]['@id'];
```